# Combine two PHP arrays match the columns deposit and date

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays.

This first array holds the deposit amount.

```
array (
  0 => '0.4',
  1 => '0.1',
)
```

This second array holds the deposit date.

```
array (
  0 => '2019-10-30',
  1 => '2019-10-28',
)
```

I need them combined like this.

```
array (
  0 => '0.4',
  1 => '2019-10-30',
  2 => '0.1',
  3 => '2019-10-28',
)
```

Alternatively how could I also combine them like this as well.

```
array (
  0.4 => '2019-10-30',
  0.1 => '2019-10-28',
)
```

I know this is simple and I must just be real tired tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [array_combine function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$keys = array (0 => '0.4', 1 => '0.1');
$values = array (0 => '2019-10-30', 1 => '2019-10-28',);
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/0eDqa)

Comment: I was doing array_merge, not array_combine. Anyway, this is what I needed thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use next code:

```
$ar1 = [0.4, 0.1];
$ar2 = ['2019-10-30', '2019-10-28'];
$ar_res = [];

for ($i=0;$i<count($ar1);$i++){
    $ar_res[] = $ar1[$i];
    $ar_res[] = $ar2[$i];
}
print_r($ar_res);
```

or next

```
$ar1 = [0.4, 0.1];
$ar2 = ['2019-10-30', '2019-10-28'];
$ar_res = [];

for ($i=0;$i<count($ar1);$i++){
    $ar_res[(string)($ar1[$i])] = $ar2[$i];
}
print_r($ar_res);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dab4114c1c8af5525e69b09e7cb221e4f372c31e)

Comment: Good easy to understand